# Is it possible to create a faster computer from many computers?

Tags: windows

How can I use several computers to create a faster environment? I have about 12 computers with 4GB each and 2GHz each. I need to run some time consuming data transform and would like to use the combined power of these machines. They are all running Win2003 server.

Basically we have a large number of video files that we need to transform so our analysts can do their analysis. The problem is complicated by the fact I can't tell you more about the project.

I moved it to: https://serverfault.com/questions/40615/is-it-possible-to-create-a-faster-computer-from-many-computers

Comment: Good question but this might better be asked on Serverfault.com

Comment: $10 says "some time consuming data transform" == brute force attack or other nefarious activity ;)

Comment: I would guess it's a programming question as the program will probably need tailoring to work across multiple machines

Comment: Now @Chris McCall, be nice ;) I was just reading about how I can render my non-linear video editing projects much faster using networked, distributed computers. There are countless application that can be solved using distributed computing.

Comment: This could easily become a programming question if you would just tell us what algorithm you're using.

Comment: @Nick, you might be right. I read it as "how to network computers to run faster." I guess the question could be asked from a "how to program distributed systems" point of view.

Comment: Really guys? This is his first post ever on SO and you close it? This is a totally valid question that should be answered. In today's world, parallelism is important. +1 for reopen.

Comment: What is with the quickdraw closing? Everyone, relax. Not programming related does not mean "not related to YOUR programming".

Comment: Bring this to serverfault, I'd love to post an answer about HPC clustering

Comment: @Jim Even so, it needs to be reopened before it can be moved. Its ridiculous how people close legitimate questions and then don't even migrate them to an appropriate place.

Comment: @Chris yes, but white hat nefariousness or black hat nefariousness?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's called [Grid Computing](http://www.gridforum.org/) or more recently, Cloud Computing.

There are many programming toolkits that are available to distribute your operations across a network. Everything from doing builds to database operations to complex mathematics libraries to special parallel programming languages.

There are solutions for every size product, from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/grid/) and [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technologies/grid/index.html) down to smaller vendors like [Globus](http://www.globus.org/). And there are even open-source solutions, such as [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/) and [NGrid](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/) (the latter is on SourceForge).

Answer (score 2):

You will get speed only if you can split the job and run it on multiple computers parallely. Can you do that with your data transform program? One of the things I am aware of is that Amazon supports map-reduce. If you can express your data transform problem as a map-reduce problem, you can potentially leverage Amazon's cloud based Hadoop service.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no "out of the box" way to just combine multiple computers into one big computer in a generic way like that.

The idea here is distributed computing, and you would have to write a program (possibly using an existing framework) that would essentially split your data transform into smaller chunks, send those off to each of the other computers to process, then aggregate the results.

Whether this would work or not would depend on the nature of your problem - can it be split into multiple chunks that can be worked on independently or not?

If so, there are several existing frameworks out there that you could use to build such an application.  [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/core/) for example, which uses [Map-Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Your program will probably need to be modified to to take advantage of multiple machines.

One method of doing this is to use an implementation of [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) (possibly [MSMPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Messaging_Passing_Interface) as you're using Windows Server)

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [Condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/).  Their homepage is light on info, so check out the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condor_High-Throughput_Computing_System) article first.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of tools out there that can use a distributed network of computers.

An example is [Incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/)

Comment: +1 for incredibuild! Love that one :D Don't they have a product for generic computation now as well?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a [Beowulf cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_(computing)) of these things!